# Why these errors <identifier> expected and ';' expected are occurring in below code?

Tags: java, instance-variables

Code :

```
class Singleton{
    Public String str="";
    Private Singleton()
    {  }
    public static  Singleton getSingleInstance()
    {
        return new Singleton();
    }       
}
```

Error message:

```
Main.java:10: error: ';' expected
    Public String str="";
                 ^
Main.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
    Public String str="";
                 ^
```

Ques:Why these errors 1)  expected and 2)';' expected are occurring in below code?

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive; the keyword is `public`. Not `Public`.

Comment: And `private`, not `Private`, as well.